# If a motor driver IC has shoot-through protection does the controller need to add deadtime?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, h-bridge, reliability, shoot-through

I'm designing a motor driver and controller system for an E-Bike, and I'm currently using the [IRSM836-084MA](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irsm836-084ma.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567f2ba0289c). The datasheet mentions that it has "cross-conduction prevention logic", but to my knowledge it doesn't mention any sort of deadtime injection. So far, I haven't had problems with it, but in the interest of reliability, would it be advisable to add deadtime to the signals coming from the ESP32-C3 I'm using as the signal generator, instead of simply inverting the HIN and LIN outputs? Not having to deal with deadtime would greatly simplify my software, but I didn't want to rely on a failsafe system for normal operation.

Comment: This chip would not be my first choice for a typical 36 V E bike system. I assume you don't need the high voltage capability but will suffer from too high Rds(on). It is designed for lower PWM frequencies as normally used in such systems.

Comment: I'm aiming for a 15-17 kHz PWM frequency, and the system runs at roughly 60V, hence the high-voltage capabilities.

Comment: I understand. My impression is, that you probably don't need a dedicated dead time. If you create the HIN from LIN or vice versa by inverters, then there will be an overlap of some ns, the propagation delay of the inverters. This produces a short negative dead time at one end of the transitions where both are high. Send the original signals through not inverting buffers with the same delay to compensate this.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Would it be a bad idea to use the ESP32-C3's built in GPIO inverters?

Answer (score 1):

From @Jens (see comments on original post):

> you probably don't need a dedicated dead time. If you create the HIN from LIN or vice versa by inverters, then there will be an overlap of some ns, the propagation delay of the inverters. This produces a short negative dead time at one end of the transitions where both are high. Send the original signals through not inverting buffers with the same delay to compensate this.

Comment: The usual way would be to invite the author of the comment to place it as answer and accept it later, but I see the nice intention

Comment: Got it. Sorry, I'm a fairly new user so I don't know the customs here..